# Error called object is not a function or functionpointer

Tags: c, function

I have this piece of easy code with a mistake. I don't understand why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int buffer[4]={1,2,3,4};
    int** Matrix;
    Matrix=Matrix(buffer);
}


int** Matrix(int* buffer){
    int ** Matrix;
    Matrix= malloc(sizeof(buffer)*sizeof(buffer));
    int j,i;
    for(j=0;j<sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(int);j++){
        for(i=0;i<sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(int);i++){
            Matrix[j][i]=buffer[i];}}
    return Matrix;
}
```

compiling this code produces error

> Error called object is not a function or function pointer

Comment: It is generally not wise to try to name a variable and a function with the same name in C.

Comment: Is the mistake a compilation error, a compilation warning, or an algorithmic mistake? It's hard for us to guess, and most of will probably just skip this question because we don't know what you expect. Tell us what indicates the problem, and any input and (un-)expected output you might have.

Comment: I mean the function Matrix returns an int**  and my object Matrix is also from type int**  why does  gcc say  its not a function or functionpointer

Answer (score 2):

In main

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int buffer[4]={1,2,3,4};
    int** Matrix;
    Matrix=Matrix(buffer);
}
```

local variable with name Matrix declared like

```
    int** Matrix;
```

refers to itself in statement

```
    Matrix=Matrix(buffer);
```

However this expression

```
Matrix(buffer)
```

is invalid in C for pointers.

It is evident that you mean the function with the same name Matrix. But it must be declared at least in the global namespace before using it. And moreover the local variable will hide the name of the function.

So you should use different names for the pointer and the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int** Matrix(int* buffer);

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int buffer[4]={1,2,3,4};
    int** m;
    m = Matrix(buffer);
}


int** Matrix(int* buffer){
    //... the body of the function
}
```

Take into account that the function itself is also incorrect. For example in this statement

```
for(j=0;j<sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(int);j++){
```

sizeof( buffer ) does not mean the size of the array that is used as the argument. It means just the size of a pointer of type `int *`
Thus for example expression

```
sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(int)
```

maybe equal to 2 or to 1 depending on whether `sizeof( int * )` is equal to 8 or 4 and correspondingly `sizeof( int )` also is equal either to 8 or to 4.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have got a variable and a function with the same name (identifier).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.1, *Scopes of identifiers*

> [...] If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
>   space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will end
>   strictly before the scope of the other entity (the outer scope). **Within the inner scope, the
>   identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer
>   scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.**

Now, inside `main()`, the variable `Matrix` is in local scope, which takes precedence over the (flie scope) function name (also `Matrix`), hence the function is not *visible* from the `main()` which causes the error.

Change either of the identifier to make both of them unique.

Also, as correctly mentioned by [TZof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5895811/tzof) in the other answer, if a function has been *used* before it is *defined*, compiler has no way to know the function return type and argument details. Do either

- Move the function definition before `main()`
- Add a [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) of the function before `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

there are two errors:

1. a variable and a function with the same name `Matrix`
2. The function Matrix is under the main function but gcc cannot make the link of the function Matrix. It did not identifie the function.Put the Matrix function's above the main.

Comment: `but gcc must have no function under the main.`  can you quote something?

Comment: "*... gcc must have no function under the main.*" As it stands, this is nonsense.

Comment: Indeed,Corrected sorry for my english. Gcc doesn't know Matrix function return type.